# Cystic Fibrosis Genetic Risk Determination

Tags: genetics, homework

Let's say Jane has Cystic Fibrosis and we know her brother doesn't. What are the chances of her brother's future child having CF? (The chances of Cystic Fibrosis in the general population can be taken as 1 in 25)

My apologies for the very incomplete question, this was all I could remember of the actual question.
And the solution went like something along the lines of:

Possibility of Jane's brother's partner having CF: 1 in 25

Possibility of Jane's brother being a carrier: 2 in 3

And this is the part that I am not getting. For me, Jane's brother could only have a 1 in 2 chance of being a carrier (Cc or CC). But the solution went CC, Cc or cC-- this last one, cC, how is that possible? If it's a recessive trait, do we not write the dominant one first? Then how could there be cC and Cc as two separate possibilities?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. In general, we expect you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). In particular, this "addresses a basic biology concept that may seem trivial to biology professionals" and thus fits this sites criteria for ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework). (Note this can apply to questions not assigned as homework.) Thanks! 

Comment: I have found that when learning about a new area starting with a relatively accessible and reliable source like [Khan Academy](http://khanacademy.org/science/biology/) is very helpful. Wikipedia is also generally a good starting point and you can then check their references. Online platforms called MOOCs offer free (or very low cost) courses on a wide variety of subjects — two I am familiar with are [Coursera](http://coursera.org) and [edX](http://edx.org). Finally, textbooks with a good level of detail are also freely available online e.g. from [NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/).

Answer (score 2):

> And this is the part that I am not getting. For me, Jane's brother
> could only have a 1 in 2 chance of being a carrier (Cc or CC).

Wrong, because **those are not equally likely**.

There are 4 **equally likely** possibilities for any of Jane's siblings:

inherit good allele from Mom, good from Dad,

inherit bad allele from Mom, good from Dad,

inherit good allele from Mom, bad from Dad,

inherit bad allele from Mom, bad from Dad.

We know that the last is not the case for the brother.  The first 3 are still equally likely.  And in 2/3, brother is a carrier.

Answer (score 0):

Let me elaborate on swbarnes2’s answer.

The “Possibility of Jane's brother being a carrier” is indeed the trickiest part of the overall question. I have seen that even some teachers of genetics were puzzled when seeing the correct answer (2/3).

It is true that before the brother is born the probability of he being *Cc* is given by the standard Mendelian rule, which states, for a *Cc* x *Cc* mating, ¼ of the offspring will be *CC*, ¼ *cc*, **and ½ *Cc***.

But that answer ignores the fact that the brother is already born and (presumably) has an age by which all *cc* homozygotes have been recognized. Then, we know that he is not *cc* and can only be *CC* or *Cc*, whose probabilities sum up to ¾. It follows that he is *Cc* with probability ½ / ¾ = 2/3.

This kind of problems are generally tackled by using the Bayes theorem, which is a way to transform a prior probability into a posterior probability. In this case, we know that the prior probability, Pr(*Cc*), of the brother being a carrier is 50%, and want to calculate the posterior probability, Pr(*Cc* | *not-cc*), which is the probability that he is a carrier *given that he is not affected*. The Bayesian rule has the general form

Pr(A|B) = Pr (B|A) x Pr(A)/P(B),

which in our case reads

Pr(*Cc*|*not-cc*) = Pr(*not-cc*|*Cc*) x Pr(*Cc*)/Pr(*not-cc*).

As the first factor in this equation equals 1 (it is certain that a subject is not *cc* if he is *Cc*), it easy to see that the solution corresponds to the above, perhaps more intuitive, calculation. In more complex situations (consider for example if Jane's brother is young, and a certain proportion of *cc* subjects are diagnosed only late in life) the Bayes rule is useful, as it help decomposing the problem.